# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to write a program, and I want the program to read a line.

it is giving me this error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int

How can I convert the string to int? This is the part of the program that's giving the error.

```
class engineering : faculty
{
    public engineering()    \\constructor
    {
    }
    public int maths_grade;

    public override void fill_form()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Insert Maths Grades: ");
        int maths_grade = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't assign string to an int. You have to Convert it. `int maths_grade = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` or Parse it using `int.TryParse` or `int.Parse`. Read about **[Casting and Type Conversions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)**

Comment: The return value of Console's ReadLine() is a string. You are trying to set maths_grade's value to a string. (but maths_grade is a defined as int!) So, in order to convert a string to an int you could use Convert.ToInt32(stringComesHere) or other method in the answers below.

Comment: If you are new to programming you should probably learn how to search for the errors you get before writing questions on Stackoverflow (I really think it will save you time). I can recommend [google](http://www.google.se) which finds 706 000 results based on your title. searching for [convert string to int](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+string+to+int+c%23&oq=convert+string+to+&aqs=chrome.3.57j0j5j0j62j60.6910j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) gives 1 750 000 results. Take your pick

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
int maths_grade = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

because `ReadLine` returns `string`, then you need to parse it to get `int`. But this will throw an exception if line won't contain valid string (number). You can better check this by using `TryParse` version:

```
string line = Console.ReadLine();
int maths_grade;
if (!int.TryParse(line, out maths_grade))
{
    // Do some kind of error handling
}
```

Comment: @DarrenYoung, I've added it just after your comment

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
int mathsGrade;
if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out mathsGrade))
{
     //Do something with grade
}
else
{
     //Do something to warn of invalid input.
}
```

Comment: Why has this been downvoted?  It's a perfectly reasonable approach?

Comment: I suspect someone has been downvoting answers that are same as the first answer... whoever is doing this needs to stop.